# Perl cgi script to receive binary file using http put

Tags: perl

I would like to write a perl cgi script to receive binary file sent using http put method. The script will read the binary contents of file and store it in a folder.

Can somebody please share the code?

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) StackOverflow is a not "plz send teh codes" forum.

Answer (score 2):

The [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) module can handle that.

```
my $data = $cgi->param('PUTDATA');
```